# Como concatenar instruções SQL?

Tags: php, sql

```
$tarefa1 = "ALTER TABLE imovel DROP COLUMN CAMPONULL"; 
$tarefa2 = "ALTER TABLE imovel ADD ENDERECO VARCHAR(300)"; 
$tarefa3 = "ALTER TABLE imovel ADD COMPLEMENTO VARCHAR(3000)";

$pdo->exec($tarefa1, $tarefa2, $tarefa3); <----------
```

Sei que aonde está a seta é incorreto, como posso proceder para concatenar diversas instruções SQL fazendo com que elas sejam executadas simultaneamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html), você não pode ADD e DROP em uma mesma função, entretanto pode dividir todos os DROP e ADD.

Basicamente o seguinte:

```
   for($i = 0; $i < count($nome_add); $i++){  //puramente exemplo, pois não disse de onde vinha o nome!
        $add .= "ADD ".$nome_add." VARCHAR(300),";   // ADD Coluna1 VARCHAR(300),ADD Coluna2 VARCHAR(300),ADD Coluna3 VARCHAR(300),  
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($nome_drop); $i++){  //puramente exemplo, pois não disse de onde vinha o nome!
        $drop .= $nome_drop.",";         // = Coluna1,Coluna2,Coluna3
    }



    $pdo->exec("ALTER TABLE imovel ".trim($add, ",")); //ALTER TABLE imovel ADD Coluna1 VARCHAR(300),ADD Coluna2 VARCHAR(300),ADD Coluna3 VARCHAR(300)
    $pdo->exec("ALTER TABLE imovel DROP COLUMN ".trim($drop, ",")); //ALTER TABLE imovel DROP COLUMN Coluna1,Coluna2,Coluna3
```